# (Java)Why does my decimal to binary conversion method only work some of the time when counting consecutive integers in a character array?

Tags: java, arrays, binary, decimal, counting

I'm a novice Java coder working on a problem dealing with counting consecutive integers in the binary forms of numbers.

The numbers are read from the input, and converted to binary using the method called conversion. The binary form is then sent to a character array where the for loop checks for consecutive characters(specifically the number 1) and prints the maximum count as the final answer.

I've managed to get the code to a state where I feel it should be working, but I've only had success with about half of the test cases. The larger number conversions like 262,141 tend to produce incorrect answers. Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

I have a suspicion that it's something to do with the character array, but after several hours of research I haven't been able to find a solution to my particular problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {


    public static int conversion(int decimal){//this will take the decimal from the input and convert it to binary

        int result = 0;//the result from each step of the conversion
        int base = 1;//used to multiply the remainder by 1, 10, 100 etc 

        while(decimal > 0){
            int remainder = decimal % 2;//takes the remainder of the iteration
            decimal = decimal / 2;//halves the decimal number
            result = result + (remainder * base);//pseudo concatenation of the binary
            base = base * 10;//increases the base multiplier to continue filling out the binary leftward
        }        
        return result;//returns result after loop has finished

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
        int n = scan.nextInt();//scan the input to obtain the decimal number        

        int binaryForm = conversion(n);//convert the decimal to binary and assign to binaryForm variable        
        String stringForm = Integer.toString(binaryForm);//convert binaryForm to a String

        int counter = 1;
        int max = 1;
        char testArray[] = stringForm.toCharArray();//send stringForm to fill out testArray

        for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length - 1; i++){//loops through testArray to test stringForm values

            if(testArray[i] == testArray[i + 1] && testArray[i] == '1'){//if consecutive values equal char 1, increase counter
                counter += 1;
                if(counter > max){
                    max = counter;//if counter is higher than current maxCounter, increase maxCounter
                }
            }

            else {//if consecutive values do not equal 1, reset counter
                counter = 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(max);//print the maximum consecutive values for the decimal input when converted to binary

    }
}
```

Comment: Total confusion here. There is no decimal to binary conversion in `conversion()`. Your method *receives* a binary number and converts it to some other number by a completely erroneous process. The only decimal to binary conversion anywhere in your code takes place in `scan.nextInt()`.

Comment: I'd have to disagree, the method receives a decimal number which is scanned in main and converts it into binary through modulus and division. That and the consecutive integer counting are the whole point of the exercise :)

Comment: No. `int decimal` is already binary, by definition, and `Scanner.nextInt()` performs a decimal to binary conversion, also by definition. You need to either just use the result of `nextInt()` directly as the binary number, or, if you're supposed to code your own conversion, pass the input to `conversion()` as a `String`, not as a parsed binary integer. The 'modulus and division' process you have written is complete nonsense. You are multiplying binary digits by 10. You would need to modulo and divide by 10, and multiply by 10, when it is instantly obvious that it accomplishes exactly nothing.

Comment: Well, `261,141` in decimal is `11,1111,1111,1111,1101` in binary. Assigning this value to an `int` in decimal would result in integer overflow, thus your algorithm cannot surpass this either. I recommend to directly build a `string` representation.

Comment: The scanner is reading integers ranging from 5 to the 262,141 from an external source. I can assure you that these numbers come in as integers, must be converted to their binary form, and are then sent to a character array where the consecutive integers are counted. Like I stated in the introductory post, the code is working for most cases and it has been tested thoroughly. If you'd take the time to give it a look I would very much appreciate it, as I'm at a loss as to why only some values are producing the correct answers.

Comment: I didn't think of overflow issues at all, Izruo! Thank you so much for the response, I'll definitely have to utilize strings as a workaround for the larger numbers.

Comment: I can assure you that `Scanner.nextInt()` *does* convert decimal strings to their binary form, and that any variable of type `int` contains binary. Please stop arguing about this, it is extremely basic material. You need to sort out your confusions before anybody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a binary representation of a decimal number using an integer. This will work for smaller numbers but it doesn't take long for you to reach an overflow. You should use a string representation of the binary number like so

```
    String numBin = "";
    while(num > 0)
    {
        numBin = num % 2 + numBin;
        num = num / 2;
    }
    System.out.println("Binary Representation: " + numBin);
```

Then take that string and loop through it calculating the consecutive counts of 1's

```
    int consecutiveCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numBin.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if(numBin.charAt(i) == '1' && numBin.charAt(i + 1) == '1')
        {
            consecutiveCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Consecutive Count: " + consecutiveCount);
```

Output

```
Number: 261141
Binary Representation: 111111110000010101
Consecutive Count: 7

Number: 3
Binary Representation: 11
Consecutive Count: 1

Number: 18
Binary Representation: 10010
Consecutive Count: 0

Number: 1111111
Binary Representation: 100001111010001000111
Consecutive Count: 5
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for identifying the issue and providing an alternative!